# Wordpress Custom Post-type Pagination 404 w/ WP-Pagenavi

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress

I need to pull two custom post types for a project I am working on. I am passing them to post_type as an array. On the front they are separated into two different list classes, smiles and ads. They show up, but pagination breaks. I have set my permalinks with %postname%, edited the settings for Page navi, and still reading 404.

The url's should read as /smiles/page/*/, which they do, but as 404.

Here's the code.

```
        <?php 
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                  'post_type' => array ('smiles','ads'),
                  'order' => 'DESC',
                  'posts_per_page' =>'3',
                  'paged' => $paged ));

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();    
        ?>
            <?php if ($post->post_type == 'smiles') { ?>
            <li class=smile>
                <h3><?php the_author(); ?></h3>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class=x-fi><img src="<?php echo get_first_image(); ?>" /></a>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <?php echo getPostLikeLink( get_the_ID() ); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More / Comment...</a>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ($post->post_type == 'ads') { ?>
            <li class=ad>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>                  
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $the_query ) ); wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Edit 1:

Checked some posts. Changed $the_query to $wp_query with no results.

Comment: Have you tried re-saving the permalinks https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen ?

Comment: Yes. I switched them to default and then back.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it.

The simple solution was to remove the plugin and add a custom function to handle pagination. After that I changed the reading posts for the 'blog' pages to 1 and updated permalinks. Then pagination started working.

Full solution:

functions.php

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 2) {  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class='pagination'>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
```

archive-smiles.php

```
<?php   
                $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                          'post_type' => array ('smiles','ads'),
                          'order' => 'DESC',
                          'posts_per_page' =>'2',
                          'paged' => $paged
                          ));

                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();    
                ?>
                    <?php if ($post->post_type == 'smiles') { ?>
                    <li class=smile>
                        <h3><?php the_author(); ?></h3>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class=x-fi><img src="<?php echo get_first_image(); ?>" /></a>
                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <?php echo getPostLikeLink( get_the_ID() ); ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More / Comment...</a>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ($post->post_type == 'ads') { ?>
                    <li class=ad>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>                  
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php pagination( $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
```